# List API name not visible while creating new list view in lightning

Tags: lightning, lightning-experience, list-view

When I am logged in as a user of Profile A,  The following fields are displayed: List Name and List API name

[image]

But When I log in as a user of Profile B, the List API name is not visible.
[image]

Is there any configuration or access missing for the profile? Please guide.